# Ubuntu 18 command apt-get dist-upgrade -qq --force-yes deprecated

Tags: linux, ubuntu

when I tried as

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -qq --force-yes
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
```

Then tried the suggested as:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -qq --allow
E: Command line option --allow is not understood in combination with the other options
```

So how to use the above commad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the message, you are suggested to use the options **starting with** `--allow`.

Have a look in the `apt-get̀` man page, you will find options like :

- `--allow-downgrades`
- `--allow-remove-essential`
- `--allow-unauthenticated`

and so on.

when you have a look at the `--force-yes` option description, you can also find interesting informations :

```
       --force-yes
           Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially harmful. It should not be used
           except in very special situations. Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration Item: APT::Get::force-yes. This is deprecated and
           replaced by --allow-unauthenticated , --allow-downgrades , --allow-remove-essential , --allow-change-held-packages in 1.1.
```

Comment: What I needed was --allow-change-held-packages instead of --force-yes

Comment: @PHZ.fi-Pharazon Yes, same for me.